# How to post on Facebook from an external web application?

Tags: facebook, web-applications, content-management-system

I'm planning to create a [CMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system)-like web application for a small society. There is a requirement to post on members' [Facebook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook) accounts when a article is published on the web site, at least as a notification or link with brief heading so that users can click on it and read the full article at site.

I do not know whether this is feasible even. If this can be accomplish, can someone guide me how?